# %lprun-like module profiling using kernprof

Tags: python, profiling, line-profiler

I would like to profile certain modules using kernprof without inserting `@profile` decorators. Inside IPython shell `%lprun` has awesome feature `-m module` which allows to profile all lines in a specified module. But if I need to run some script from the command I use `kernprof`. The latter unfortunately doesn't seem to have this functionality allowing to profile only using the decorator. How can I bring this module-profiling functionality to command line `kernprof` invocation?